# Always show authentication dialog box when using LinkedIn

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Within our application there's a possibility of using authentication with OAuth 2.0 several times. First authentication will show us an *authentication dialog box*, when we want to do it one more time (second authentication) we are redirected without *authentication dialog box* to `redirect_uri`.

How is it possible to always see the *authentication dialog box*?

Comment: What language / framework are you using? This maybe important info for this question

Comment: it's ruby, ruby-on-rails.

Comment: but I think it is not important for this. it must be in api. and I found nothing about this in linkedin api docs

Answer (score 0):

That will **generally require support from the identity provider** and as far as I'm aware LinkedIn does not support this, neither in a standard way or provider-specific way.

In accordance to the standards this would be accomplished by using the [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) `prompt` parameter when performing an authentication request. You would pass the `login` value and the provider, if compliant to the specification, would need to:

> **login**
>
> The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User for reauthentication. If it cannot reauthenticate the End-User, it MUST return an error, typically `login_required`.

However, I don't know how widespread support for this is. In LinkedIn, I think support is nil. Google also does not list the `login` option as a supported [value in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#re-consent), however, they support `select_account` which may solve some scenarios. Another example, Auth0 does support the reauthentication through `prompt=consent` although it's not documented anywhere, so might change.